# Girlfriend got a parking ticket for parking in front of her own house. Is this legal?

Tags: parking

My Girlfriend goes to University of Mary Washington in Fredricksburg VA. She got a parking ticket because she parked on the street in front of the house she rents. On the street there's a sign that says no UMW student parking but she didn't think this applied if you own the property and she's lived there for 10 months and hasn't gotten a ticket yet.

Is there any way she could get out of this ticket?

Comment: Ask the municipality that makes the laws, the LEO who issued the citation, the court that will adjudicate it, or a licensed attorney.

Comment: If she rents she doesn't own it, BTW.

Comment: @Andy would that affect this scenario?

Comment: It might.  The sign says no students, it may not matter that she rents.  It should (in my non-legal opinion) be allowed just like anyone else renting would likely be allowed to park there, but who knows what wacky regulations are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can contest a parking ticket if you have a legal basis, and they even provide [a form](http://www.fredericksburgva.gov/DocumentCenter/View/6781). Some streets require resident parking permits, and for some you have to know [where to look it up](http://ecode360.com/28968407). There are also streets adjacent to the university where the university regulates parking permits. Finally, there is a general "parking in one spot too long" ordinance. So it matters where exactly you are.